# show username in nav memberpage

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the username of the user session.

I hope that you have entered all the necessary files

(It's not my code)

member.php

```
//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); }
<nav>
<?php echo [code] ?>
</nav>
<!-- Html code -->
```

config.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','database username');
define('DBPASS','password');
define('DBNAME','database name');

//application address
define('DIR','http://domain.com/');
define('SITEEMAIL','noreply@domain.com');

try {

//create PDO connection 
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
//show error
echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
exit;
}

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
$user = new User($db); 
?>
```

user.php

```
<?php
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

private $_db;

function __construct($db){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_db = $db;
}

private function get_user_hash($username){  

    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        return $row['password'];

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
}

public function login($username,$password){

    $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

    if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        return true;
    }   
}

public function logout(){
    session_destroy();
}

public function is_logged_in(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
        return true;
    }       
}

}


?>
```

password.php

```
<?php
   if (!defined('PASSWORD_BCRYPT')) {
    define('PASSWORD_BCRYPT', 1);
    define('PASSWORD_DEFAULT', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
 }

Class Password {

public function __construct() {}


/**
 * Hash the password using the specified algorithm
 *
 * @param string $password The password to hash
 * @param int    $algo     The algorithm to use (Defined by PASSWORD_* constants)
 * @param array  $options  The options for the algorithm to use
 *
 * @return string|false The hashed password, or false on error.
 */
function password_hash($password, $algo, array $options = array()) {
    if (!function_exists('crypt')) {
        trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_hash to function", E_USER_WARNING);
        return null;
    }
    if (!is_string($password)) {
        trigger_error("password_hash(): Password must be a string", E_USER_WARNING);
        return null;
    }
    if (!is_int($algo)) {
        trigger_error("password_hash() expects parameter 2 to be long, " . gettype($algo) . " given", E_USER_WARNING);
        return null;
    }
    switch ($algo) {
        case PASSWORD_BCRYPT :
            // Note that this is a C constant, but not exposed to PHP, so we don't define it here.
            $cost = 10;
            if (isset($options['cost'])) {
                $cost = $options['cost'];
                if ($cost < 4 || $cost > 31) {
                    trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Invalid bcrypt cost parameter specified: %d", $cost), E_USER_WARNING);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            // The length of salt to generate
            $raw_salt_len = 16;
            // The length required in the final serialization
            $required_salt_len = 22;
            $hash_format = sprintf("$2y$%02d$", $cost);
            break;
        default :
            trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Unknown password hashing algorithm: %s", $algo), E_USER_WARNING);
            return null;
    }
    if (isset($options['salt'])) {
        switch (gettype($options['salt'])) {
            case 'NULL' :
            case 'boolean' :
            case 'integer' :
            case 'double' :
            case 'string' :
                $salt = (string)$options['salt'];
                break;
            case 'object' :
                if (method_exists($options['salt'], '__tostring')) {
                    $salt = (string)$options['salt'];
                    break;
                }
            case 'array' :
            case 'resource' :
            default :
                trigger_error('password_hash(): Non-string salt parameter supplied', E_USER_WARNING);
                return null;
        }
        if (strlen($salt) < $required_salt_len) {
            trigger_error(sprintf("password_hash(): Provided salt is too short: %d expecting %d", strlen($salt), $required_salt_len), E_USER_WARNING);
            return null;
        } elseif (0 == preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9./]+$#D', $salt)) {
            $salt = str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($salt));
        }
    } else {
        $buffer = '';
        $buffer_valid = false;
        if (function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv') && !defined('PHALANGER')) {
            $buffer = mcrypt_create_iv($raw_salt_len, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
            if ($buffer) {
                $buffer_valid = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$buffer_valid && function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
            $buffer = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($raw_salt_len);
            if ($buffer) {
                $buffer_valid = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$buffer_valid && is_readable('/dev/urandom')) {
            $f = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
            $read = strlen($buffer);
            while ($read < $raw_salt_len) {
                $buffer .= fread($f, $raw_salt_len - $read);
                $read = strlen($buffer);
            }
            fclose($f);
            if ($read >= $raw_salt_len) {
                $buffer_valid = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$buffer_valid || strlen($buffer) < $raw_salt_len) {
            $bl = strlen($buffer);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $raw_salt_len; $i++) {
                if ($i < $bl) {
                    $buffer[$i] = $buffer[$i] ^ chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
                } else {
                    $buffer .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
                }
            }
        }
        $salt = str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($buffer));
    }
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, $required_salt_len);

    $hash = $hash_format . $salt;

    $ret = crypt($password, $hash);

    if (!is_string($ret) || strlen($ret) <= 13) {
        return false;
    }

    return $ret;
}

/**
 * Get information about the password hash. Returns an array of the information
 * that was used to generate the password hash.
 *
 * array(
 *    'algo' => 1,
 *    'algoName' => 'bcrypt',
 *    'options' => array(
 *        'cost' => 10,
 *    ),
 * )
 *
 * @param string $hash The password hash to extract info from
 *
 * @return array The array of information about the hash.
 */
function password_get_info($hash) {
    $return = array('algo' => 0, 'algoName' => 'unknown', 'options' => array(), );
    if (substr($hash, 0, 4) == '$2y$' && strlen($hash) == 60) {
        $return['algo'] = PASSWORD_BCRYPT;
        $return['algoName'] = 'bcrypt';
        list($cost) = sscanf($hash, "$2y$%d$");
        $return['options']['cost'] = $cost;
    }
    return $return;
}

/**
 * Determine if the password hash needs to be rehashed according to the options provided
 *
 * If the answer is true, after validating the password using password_verify, rehash it.
 *
 * @param string $hash    The hash to test
 * @param int    $algo    The algorithm used for new password hashes
 * @param array  $options The options array passed to password_hash
 *
 * @return boolean True if the password needs to be rehashed.
 */
function password_needs_rehash($hash, $algo, array $options = array()) {
    $info = password_get_info($hash);
    if ($info['algo'] != $algo) {
        return true;
    }
    switch ($algo) {
        case PASSWORD_BCRYPT :
            $cost = isset($options['cost']) ? $options['cost'] : 10;
            if ($cost != $info['options']['cost']) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Verify a password against a hash using a timing attack resistant approach
 *
 * @param string $password The password to verify
 * @param string $hash     The hash to verify against
 *
 * @return boolean If the password matches the hash
 */
public function password_verify($password, $hash) {
    if (!function_exists('crypt')) {
        trigger_error("Crypt must be loaded for password_verify to function", E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }
    $ret = crypt($password, $hash);
    if (!is_string($ret) || strlen($ret) != strlen($hash) || strlen($ret) <= 13) {
        return false;
    }

    $status = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($ret); $i++) {
        $status |= (ord($ret[$i]) ^ ord($hash[$i]));
    }

    return $status === 0;
}

}
```

thank you very much for who is able to help me

Comment: Would need to see password class. However what soes `var_dump($user);` show?

Comment: Add password classes

Comment: well i dont see any methods that access or store any user details beyond the password. You would need to edit the class to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this after your `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;` line in `user.php` : `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` like this :

```
<?php 
    public function login($username,$password){

        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            return true;
        }   
    }
?>
```

and then edit your `member.php`  :

```
<nav>
    <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: Tried but doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/q7f61s6h/ like this right?

Comment: no not like that I will edit the code.